# JQuery Mobile Grid of Buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm pretty new to JQuery Mobile and I'm trying to create a 2 column 3 row grid of buttons to serve as my home screen. When I use div class="ui-grid-b", I get the look I was hoping for, but I can't get the grid items to serve as buttons that animate nicely.

If I replace the blocks in the grid with buttons, it looks very ugly.

Any advice on how to create a good looking grid of buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Is this not working for you ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AQxxp/2/))?

```
<div class="ui-grid-b">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">
            <button type="submit" data-theme="a">Button A</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">
            <button type="submit" data-theme="b">Button B</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-c">
        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e">
            <button type="submit" data-theme="c">Button C</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ui-grid-d my-grid">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <button data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true">Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <button data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true">Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-c">
        <button data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true">Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-d">
        <button data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true">Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-e">
        <button data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext" data-inline="true">Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also there is a [whole page in the documentation](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/demos/widgets/grids/grid-buttons.php) devoted to this.